# AgoraRtcEngine_iOS and agora_rtc_engine version conflict

Tags: ios, flutter, agora.io

I am using AgoraRtcEngine_iOS version 3.7.0 as Screenshare exntension for iOS native and agora_rtc_engine 5.2.0 in flutter in Same flutter project. Issue is when I am performing pod install it shows as shown below. And for old version screen share is not working fine. Does anyone know the solution ?

> The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: agoraaidenoiseextension.xcframework, agoradav1dextension.xcframework, agoraciextension.xcframework, agorafullaudioformatextension.xcframework, agorafdextension.xcframework, agorareplaykitextension.xcframework, agoracore.xcframework, agorartckit.xcframework, agorasoundtouch.xcframework, agorafdkaac.xcframework, agoraffmpeg.xcframework, agorasuperresolutionextension.xcframework, agoravideoprocessextension.xcframework, and agoravideosegmentationextension.xcframework

Answer (score 0):

You can use Agora iOS SDK version `3.6.2-fix.1` with your Flutter project

Comment: I add pod 'AgoraRtcEngine_iOS', '3.6.2-fix.1'  in podfile but it throws error - mistyped the name or version. There is no such version available https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/release_ios_video?platform=iOS

Comment: I just had a look at the cocoapod versions [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/1/d/9/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS). It's most likely 3.6.2.1 that you want for this

Comment: It is not about cocoa pod versions, It is about agora version. I want particular version which is used same in native iOS as well as in flutter. which is not available as of now.